# Is there a formula to calculate the number of In-between Points for each adjacent $2D$ lattice polygon vertices?

Tags: geometry, polygons

[**Lemma**](https://euler.genepeer.com/schinzels-theorem)

For any non-negative integer $k$, $x^2+y^2=5^k$ has $4(k+1)$ integer solutions.

For example, here are 3 circles for $k=1,2,3$. The blue dots represent the vertices (integer solutions), then connect the dots to form polygons (dash lines). The red dots represent the points in-between the vertices.

[image: CIRCLES]

Tabulated the number of In-between Points using this formula $\text{gcd}(|x_2 - x_1|, |y_2 - y_1|) - 1$ for each adjacent vertices $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ and summed them up.

```
k    Vertices 4(k+1)     In-between Points   Total polygon boundary points
1    8                   4                   12
2    12                  0                   12
3    16                  28                  44
4    20                  40                  60
5    24                  116                 140
6    28                  144                 172
7    32                  524                 556
8    36                  1272                1308
9    40                  3028                3068
10   44                  5984                6028
11   48                  10780               10828
12   52                  23440               23492
13   56                  63444               63500
14   60                  117480              117540
```

**Questions**

- Is there a pattern or formula to calculate the number of In-between
  Points for a given $k$?
- Notice for $k=2$, there are $0$ In-between Points. Do other values of $k$ exist that have no In-between Points?

I've tried random online sequence solvers to predict the next number of In-between Points and OEIS, but no luck. :(