# Approximate $\pi$ using Gauss Circle Problem and Pick's Theorem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, circles, pi

**Introduction**

For any non-negative integer $k$, $x^2+y^2=5^k$ has $4(k+1)$ integer solutions (vertices).

For example, here are 3 circles for $k=1,2,3$. The blue dots represent the vertices (integer solutions), then connect the dots to form polygons (dash lines). The red dots represent the points in-between the vertices.

[image: circle_pi]

Tabulated the number of in-between points using this formula

$$\sum_{i=0}^{4(k+1)-1} \left( \gcd \left( |x_{i+1} - x_i|, |y_{i+1} - y_i| \right) - 1 \right)$$

```
k    Vertices 4(k+1)     In-between Points
1    8                   4                   
2    12                  0                   
3    16                  28                  
4    20                  40                  
5    24                  116                 
6    28                  144                 
7    32                  524                 
8    36                  1272                
9    40                  3028                
10   44                  5984                
11   48                  10780               
12   52                  23440               
13   56                  63444               
14   60                  117480  <--- Used in the example below
```

**Approximation Formula for $\pi$**

$$\small\pi \approx
\frac{1}{5^k} \left[ 4 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{5^k}{4i+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{5^k}{4i+3} \right\rfloor \right) - 2(k+1) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^{4(k+1)-1} \left( \gcd \left( |x_{i+1} - x_i|, |y_{i+1} - y_i| \right) - 1 \right) \right]
$$

**Example**

Let $k = 14$, then

$$\small\pi \approx
\frac{1}{5^{14}} \left[ 4 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{5^{14}}{4i+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{5^{14}}{4i+3} \right\rfloor \right) - 30 - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^{59} \left( \gcd \left( |x_{i+1} - x_i|, |y_{i+1} - y_i| \right) - 1 \right) \right]
$$

Applying the precomputed value (see table above) shows

$$\sum_{i=0}^{59} \left( \gcd \left( |x_{i+1} - x_i|, |y_{i+1} - y_i| \right) - 1 \right) = 117480$$

and reduces to

$$\pi \approx
\frac{1}{5^{14}} \left[ 4 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{5^{14}}{4i+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{5^{14}}{4i+3} \right\rfloor \right) - 58770 \right]
$$

Plugging into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281%2F5%5E14%29%20*%20%284*Sum%5BFloor%5B5%5E14%2F%284i%20%2B%201%29%5D%20-%20Floor%5B5%5E14%2F%284i%20%2B%203%29%5D%2C%20%7Bi%2C%200%2C%20100000%7D%5D%20-%2058770%29) gives

$$\pi \approx 3.14158$$

**Question**

Is it possible to compute the number of in-between points on-the-fly instead of using a precomputed table lookup? I tried WolframAlpha but without success.

I've never used Mathematica but it would be nice run a calculation for $\pi$ by prepping it first and then supplying

$$\small\frac{1}{5^k} \left[ 4 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left( \left\lfloor \frac{5^k}{4i+1} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{5^k}{4i+3} \right\rfloor \right) - 2(k+1) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^{4(k+1)-1} \left( \gcd \left( |x_{i+1} - x_i|, |y_{i+1} - y_i| \right) - 1 \right) \right]
$$

[Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4712191/show-pi-%E2%89%88-frac4-sum-i-0-infty-left-left-lfloor-frac5k4i1-right-rf)

Comment: Well, working over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ you know the integer points on $x^2+y^2=5^k$ and so just sort them around the circle and thus compute the integer points on the various segments.